# Powering a crane/claw

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, amperage

I bought this claw (it came with no instructions):

[image]

It has 2 wires only. By default the claw is open. When I power it, it closes.

With 5V it barely moves, with 12V it closes but the strength is too weak. I guess I need even more power? or AMPS? Or do I need to handle this in another way with a regulator? Voltage regulator? I'm sorry I lack of experience with this part. I usually do my projects with a Raspberry Pi but never had something that takes more than 5V.

Comment: Do you have a link to that particular claw?

Comment: Yep : [link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/362768545039) ,  but the description is not even matching, the guy talks about 4 wires...hu

Comment: Ask the supplier for instructions or demand your money back.

Comment: It is mentionned "Operation: 48 Volt" on the link you provided.

Comment: @PierreOlivier it also mention 4 wires, but i only have 2 so..

Comment: Yeah you need 48V. What's the impedance between the red and white wire?

Comment: i have no idea what the impedance is between the wires

Comment: Measure it. Also, no datasheet = no sale.

Comment: @winny Eh. For hobby projects sometimes you can take the risk on parts without a datasheet (either because they are old and hard to identify or because the operation is supposed to be obvious). Maybe it should be no datasheet = no questions on SE if it turns out to be a bad idea?

Comment: @Owow Measure the resistance. I don't think it's important to know the impedance and that is harder to measure, and needs to be measured at a specific frequency which Swedgin did not specify.

Comment: Yes, I meant resistance instead of impedance.

Comment: @Owow I have similar concern as you described in the question. Have you been able to finally figure out if it works better with AC or DC. I've read that these are mostly controlled with 5~48V but TBH somehow assumed DC :(

Answer (score 2):

They **SAY**

> Crane Machine Claw Coil for 24 to 48 volt (20 ohm) claws
>   Wiring Notes:
>   This claw coil comes with four wires:Red, White, Blue and Yellow.
>   1. The yellow and Blue get wired together
>   2. The Red and White get wired together
>   This make the two wire connection needed for both 24v to 48v AC claw units.
>   The strength of the claw is normally adjustable by the voltage from the claw machine PCB board.

If I was "playing" with this and decided to try and make it work rather than asking the supplier or returning it, then -

I'd assume that this

> 1. The yellow and Blue get wired together
> 2. The Red and White get wired together
>      This make the two wire connection needed for both 24v to 48v AC claw units.

Had (probably) effectively been done and that I had a 24-48V unit.

I'd measure coil resistance.
20 Ohms? - adds to above conclusion.
10 - 15 Ohms ? - Hmmm. 
30 - + Ohms -> unhappy
Under 10 Ohms -> unhappy.

I'd try 24V.
If this was strong enough I'd check for manifest overheating for periods far longer than expected use.
If it worked well enough and not over say 40C over long periods, good enough.

If 24V not adequate, I'd use a 24V - 48V supply to investigate strength and heating.

Using DC - power = V^2/R.
If 20 Ohms then 48V = 2.4 Amps &  about 125 Watts.
I'd expect that to get very hot "rather quickly".

The lower voltage that had acceptable strength the better.
Long term operation at more or much more than say 50 degrees C MAY be OK, but I'd not risk it.

An arcade machine operator may be able to assist.
If you ARE an arcade machine operator, measuring the voltage used on a similar device may help.

AC will probably make a significant difference to the above.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I also tried with a 19V and it was too weak. So i guess i will try with a 48V AC but i need to order one

Comment: @Owow WARNING: Note that in the above I assumed DC operation and noted that AC operation will probably make a big difference. Also note that 24 V may be usefully better than 18V. Solenoids vary - the effect of changing from DC to AC may be moderate or vast. Worst case AC operation at the same voltage will BE MUCH weaker than DC operation. So you cannot 'blithely' swap between DC and AC while also changing voltages. ||  4 x 12V small lead acid batteries will allow you to try 12 / 24 / 36 / 48 volts. Or 4 "dead" 12V car batteries - as long as they can support 12V each at 2.4A for a few minutes.